# While loops and...threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, if-statement

Ive created a network game. I am having issues with (seemingly) unexplainable errors. Note that the cards are added by to the ArrayList upon mouse clicks, and this class is run on its own thread.

```
private void waitForAction(){

    tb.report("Waiting for user to make a move...");
    selectedCards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    while(selectedCards.size() < 2){
        if(selectedCards.size() == 2)//Wtf is going on here...?
            tb.report("This loop is (not) broken.");
        else
            tb.report("Looping..");
    };
    tb.report("This player has selected 2 cards.");
}
```

When I remove the else statement, the loop never exits, which is proven to me by the print(report()) methods. I had the same issue in earlier development, but it was corrected by adding the if part of the if-else statement. I am honestly baffled, logical reasoning tells me that JVM is not checking the condition because the thread is not running, however throughout the program I only ever call Thread's start() once, otherwise its untouched by my code. Any wiser sole's opinion would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post your output!

Comment: What's happening in the other thread? So far I just see one thread where selectedCards is never mutated, so it's no surprise the loop runs forever.

Comment: I suspect that the other thread is adding the cards to a different ArrayList so this one is not being modified.

Comment: You probably aren't fully recompiling your code between runs.

Comment: @ Rong - ive got over 2000 lines of code at this point with mostly graphical output, i agree its tough to solve without more but often it is the obvious things that hide from us.

Comment: @Ann As i mentioned the mouse event handler mutates the arraylist

Comment: @redge the arraylist is a class variable(global), do you mean that beyond my control this is occurring?

Comment: @Falmarri Full recompile? Can you explain? I'm using Scite which is a pretty simple editor

Comment: It still might be helpful to see what's in that event handler code.

Comment: Your code does this ` selectedCards = new ArrayList<Card>();` if your player is already assigned such an array list to their own variable they will now be looking at a different object entirely.

Comment: You have multiple threads but doing absolutely _no_ thread synchronization at all! Can't work.

Comment: There is no code to actually wait! Getting up, checking the mail box, sitting back down, getting back up, checking the mailbox, sitting back down, and continuing at breakneck speed until the mail gets there is **not** "waiting" for the mail!

Comment: Re, "ive got over 2000 lines of code...i agree its tough to solve [without seeing the whole picture]."  In other words, you have written more than 2000 lines of _untestable_ code.  Time to learn about "unit testing" and "test driven development" (a.k.a., "TDD").  Google is your friend.

Comment: There's a lot of arrogance on this forum.....

Answer (score 1):

Without more information it's hard to tell you exactly what is going wrong. However, I would strongly advise that you write your server in more of an event-based model. Especially given that it's a card game, so I'm guessing it's turn based and not real-time.

Instead of doing your loop based approach, try this:

1. The server keeps a model of the current state of the game.
2. The client sends a message to the server. One such message could be "play card XYZ"
3. The server processes the message and updates the model accordingly. If a user played a card, it might remove that card from the person's hand. It might change some other state based on the effect of the card. All the logic is handled when the message is received.
4. State changes are sent out to all the clients so that they are seeing a view consistent to the state of the server.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt! I agree, unfortunatly its hard to show more without showing all 2000+ lines... Always the problem, right? My structure I would consider event-based, however the game must wait while the human user selects two cards, as each is chosen the client requests the value of the card from the server.

Comment: the game should never need to wait.  If it is event based, the user clicking a card is the event that will trigger the logic.

Answer (score 1):

You have multithreading environment. ArrayList is not a threadSafe collection -- it does not guarantee visibility on other threads. This means your waiting thread never sees changes in the collection.

Try to use some collection of java.util.concurrency.